# Not getting normal DDL command while fetching DDL of table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I was fetching DDL of a Table using dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'A_fetch') . While fetching DDL i noticed that there are additional technical term(metdata) coming from DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE "A_test" 
(   "ID" NUMBER, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(90 BYTE) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(90 BYTE) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
"GENDER" CHAR(1 BYTE) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP"
)  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP" SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "QNBDEV" ;
```

Expected :I just want normal DDl like  `create table A_test(id number,name varchar2(90),address varchar2(90),gender char(1);`

Comment: Have a look at your settings in PL/SQL Developer. Usually you can define which options shall be printed or not.

Comment: where I need to check in PLSQL developer settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the format you want the `DBMS_METADATA` package to output using:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SQLTERMINATOR',
    TRUE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'PRETTY',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'STORAGE',
    FALSE
  );
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TABLE', 'A_test', 'SCHEMA_NAME' ) AS ddl
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| DDL |
| --- |
| CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."A_test" ("ID" NUMBER, "NAME" VARCHAR2(90), "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(90), "GENDER" CHAR(1)); |

You can also run it all as a single PL/SQL block:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SQLTERMINATOR',
    TRUE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'PRETTY',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'STORAGE',
    FALSE
  );
  SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TABLE', 'A_test', USER )
  INTO   v_sql
  FROM   DUAL;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NdcgH9GC)

Comment: I am still getting  same output. I run the block and then select statement. Its not working

Comment: @prashantchhetri It works for me in [Oracle 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/NdcgH9GC), [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/D3a8MuKR) and [Oracle 21](https://dbfiddle.uk/mkHEjmXN) (the Oracle 23 fiddle is not responding or I would have tested that as well).

Comment: It works but to some extent .I am getting this query now but still  some meta information is still coming (COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP").  Could you please advise how we can remove remaining meta data info.                      Query-->   CREATE TABLE "A_test" ("ID" NUMBER, "NAME" VARCHAR2(90) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(90) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", "GENDER" CHAR(1) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP")  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP" ;

Comment: @prashantchhetri The `DBMS_METADATA` documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-0ACD6E3B-C699-469F-8CC3-32F9DA20CA60). You can read through it and find the `SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM` section that details the `'COLLATION_CLAUSE'` option; set that to `'NEVER'` or `'NON_DEFAULT'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to generate DDL in Oracle.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME', 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME') from dual;
```

Alternately you can use describe `desc` command to describe the column name and datatype of the table, you can use the same as your DDL statement by adding crate table command and commas.

```
desc table_name;
```

Comment: I want in oracle not in postgress. Is there any option for oracle as well.

Comment: Redefined the answer for Oracle